# Reference request for monoidal structure on reflective subcategory

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, monoidal-categories

I am fairly sure the following lemma is folklore, but for some weird reason I am unable to track it down in the literature.

> Suppose $i:\mathcal{C}\hookrightarrow \mathcal{D}$ is a full reflective subcategory with reflector $L:\mathcal{D}\rightarrow \mathcal{C}$. Suppose further that $\mathcal{D}$ has a (not necessarily symmetric, not necessarily closed) monoidal structure $(\otimes,1,\alpha,\lambda,\rho)$.
>
> Assume that this tensor product *preserves local morphisms*, ie. for morphisms $f:x\rightarrow y, g:u\rightarrow v$ in $\mathcal{D}$ for which $L(f),L(g)$ become isomorphisms in $\mathcal{C}$ also the monoidal product $f\otimes g$ is local in that $L(f\otimes g)$ is an isomorphism in $\mathcal{C}$. Then $\mathcal{C}$ admits a unique monoidal structure, with tensor product $c \boxtimes c' := L(i(c)\otimes i(c'))$ and monoidal unit $L(1)$, such that $L$ is a strong monoidal functor.

The idea is to first realize that reflective subcategories are very well behaved categorical localizations at the class of local morphisms. Now, if $\mathcal{C}\subseteq \mathcal{D}$ is reflective, so is $\mathcal{C\times C}\subseteq \mathcal{D\times D}$. The condition that the tensor preserves local morphisms is precisely what one needs to obtain an induced functor on the localizations $\boxtimes:\mathcal{C\times C} \rightarrow \mathcal{C}$. Using the fact that this induced functor is a Kan-extension one can then verify that this is product of a monoidal structure on $\mathcal{C}$ as claimed.

I looked into Borceux's [Handbooks of Categorical Algebra](https://books.google.de/books/about/Handbook_of_Categorical_Algebra_Volume_2.html?id=5i2v9q0m5XAC&redir_esc=y), MacLane's [Categories for the Working Mathematician](http://www.mtm.ufsc.br/%7Eebatista/2016-2/maclanecat.pdf), Aguiar&Mahajan's [Monoidal Functors, Species and Hopf Algebras](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Emaguiar/a.pdf) and Riehl's [Category Theory in Context](https://math.jhu.edu/%7Eeriehl/context.pdf) with no avail.

If you search for monoidal reflection on the internet, [Day's reflection theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Day%27s+reflection+theorem#Day72) and Day's [Note on Monoidal Localization](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/files/DayMonoidalLocaization73.pdf) seem to be the only immediately related resources. However, if I am not mistaken, he uses the monoidal closure, which I cannot.

So, if you know a reference, please let me know. As always, thank you very much for your time.

PS: If I am not mistaken, the $\infty$-categorical analogue of this statement is proposition 2.2.1.9 in Lurie's [Higher Algebra](https://www.math.ias.edu/%7Elurie/papers/HA.pdf).

Comment: I’m not sure if you’re asking for a proof or if you’re satisfied that this is true but want a reference that you could cite in some writing you’re doing

Comment: As an aside, what’s the link between Kan extensions and monoidal structures? Does the fact that something is a Kan extension make monoidal axioms easier to verify?

Comment: I am asking for a reference. I wrote down a proof for myself, but do not believe I was the first one doing that in ordinary category theory (after all, if Lurie has it for ∞cats, it will be a known result for 1cats). The way Kan-extensions enter (in my proof) is that a monoidal structure entails 2-cells like $\lambda:1\otimes \text{id}\Rightarrow\text{id}$ and we get those for the monoidal structure on the localization, by using that the induced functors on localizations are Kan-extensions (which also have a 2-dimensional universal property)